Unsure how to improve the question
I understand that the close reason is generic and shouldn't be taken literally. That said, I believe that I've provided minimal example, accompanied with a fiddle to play with and description of the challenge. I feel that the question was closed inadequately based on the readers' presumption, not the actual content.
In fact, it's got an answer that resolved the original problem, so I can at least say that the info provided was sufficient. Now, in order to stay humble, I'm thinking maybe there's a way to make it even more clear that the presumed opinion (whatever that may be) is premature and requires a bit more insight.
I can't see it myself but I'm the one who authored it, so I may be home blind.
How to improve this question even more?

Instead of using the off-site fiddler, move it to a stack-snippet. Maybe the edit with the image should go near the explanation at the top.

Not 100% sure on this, but with "Here's a fiddle illustrating the "unfortunately" resolved issue." it sounds like the question is not complete without the contents behind that fiddle, especially because the question itself contains the CSS but not the HTML.

@rene What do you mean by "stack-snippet"? Perhaps I'm not aware of something new. The point is to allow the reader to play around and laborate with the current solution. Only posting the code (if that's what you refer to) would make it more difficult to give my problem a try. What am I missing, please?

@E_net4 Are you saying that despite the explanation above explaining that I do have a solution (proof of effort, what-have-you-tried rule), which I call an unfortunate? Or are you suggesting that it's not clear to a (sloppy) reader that I have a solution but dislike it?

You are missing out on an awesome feature: I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?  ;)

well, to be fair, if you're using the "new" stacks editor, which is part of the ask question wizard, it doesn't support stack snippets... that said i doubt your choice of demonstrating the problem is related to any votes people casted.

@KonradViltersten No, it has nothing to do with the fact that you came up with a solution, nor with how much you like it (or not). I merely pointed out that the off-site snippet appears to contain the HTML required to reproduce the problem, yet the same HTML is not in the question itself. At least one of the comments appears to agree with me on the importance of keeping all content in the question rather than behind links.

Including all content inside the question itself so the question is self-contained is a very basic rule which is absolutely not new. That being said... I do find it a little petty to close questions which have already been very successfully answered. But that's me. I don't agree with it, but I won't cast a reopen vote either if this is really, really, really what my peers want.

@Gimby i'm not so sure it has been very successfully answered, based on the op's comments on it

Also be aware that when asking a question and receiving an answer, if you find you have a follow-up question or want to go further, you should be asking a new question (e.g. click the "Ask question" button again). Do not keep editing your existing question to change it. That makes it hard for readers (and answerers) to keep up with what is being asked or answered (and it's unfair to expect answerers to do so in the first place). Downvoters might have seen that occurring here and cast downvotes based on that.

I don't really follow the html tag but in general any links that you include in your question should be additive and your question should include all the required information inside the post too. (tl;dr post the code to reproduce in the question as well as the external fiddle if not using stack snippets)

@Sayse I see your point. I fear, though, that in certain cases (as this one), it's quite a lot of code to provide (yes, a minimal example will still be quite large. I can't see the problem in providing the CSS (since it's a CSS-based solution) and also a fiddle to ease up for the reader to understand and even laborate.

@KevinB Not sure what you're referring to. The question has been answered satisfactory. I'm satisfied and using the solution. I also got greedy and asked the answerer if they could post an even further improvement. So, in this case, the question apparently contained sufficient info (but I can imagine that some people won't read the whole think and simply jump to a premature conclusion assuming that it's goofily formulated).

@TylerH I disagree that's an applicable choice for this particular case (although I agree with your point in general). I think that asking a totally new question would make it (again: in this particular case) less beneficial to the community. It wasn't substantial enough to be a real FUQ. Rather a slight adjustment.

@KonradViltersten - I think thats what the aim of the stack snippets was in respect to html examples. The problem with links is two fold - 1. The internet is untrustworthy and people are unwilling to click on a random link and 2. You aren't just asking the question for yourself, but for others that might have the same question and if the link dies by the time the next person comes across your post, then their experience will be diminished

@Sayse I've added the whole shabang now to the original question. And I will read up on the stack snippets as soon as I get some time. It was educative from many angles so I'm happy. Although, a user got angry with me for a bit unclear reason. But I'm sure it's just a misunderstanding. I will be more careful providing code on-site to counter the issues with broken links and such, in the future. Thanks. Appreciate the patience. :)

Put your Minimal Reproducible Example in the question post as well. Having a link to an off-site repro is fine, and even good. But the question post itself should also contain the full repro details. See "Help others reproduce the problem" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. For web repros, see also I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?.

@DanMašek It may not need the explaining (and, honestly speaking, it borders to patronizing tone, so I won't go there). Perhaps we could consider there might be a good intention for the omission? I believe that the CSS I posted is sufficient without the HTML (under the condition that the reader has sufficient competence) but I can imagine that it may feel as required to include the HTML too, to others. (I wasn't aware of the stack snippets, though, so you may have a point: some features hasn't been sufficiently advertised. Always nice to learn something new, though, so I'm happy.)

I'll look into that "stack snippet" feature others mentioned just like you did. Somehow, it didn't appear on my radar (or didn't work out for some reason). I'll make sure to look into that and reformulate the question to the extent it makes sense. Thanks for the hint.

@KonradViltersten I disagree. I do not think the CSS you had in revision 1 of your question is enough to understand and reproduce your setup and issue.

@starball In such case, I stand corrected. I willingly adopt to the community's opinion if it may improve others' experience. I'll amend the HTML as well (still fearing that someone else may feel it becomes too excessive). I appreciate the discussion and insights.

@KonradViltersten "sufficient without the HTML (under the condition that the reader has sufficient competence)" no, by a humongous margin. Reproducible means some future reader can tell, unambiguously and without effort, that the question is applicable to their problem, possibly by copy-and-pasting the example you provided verbatim.

@PasserBy Yes, I've noticed that there are different views regarding the sufficiency. While some may see the original payload as sufficient, there's clearly a sensation of inadequacy (admittedly, a majority's opinion, too!) so, like I wrote earlier, I stand corrected and realize that I've misjudged the required "minimality". It's been corrected now - feel free to take a peek at the revised version. I also want to express my gratitude and appreciation for the time you and others invest promoting improvement. :)
